# How to make JMX simple

Tags: java, jmx

I need to expose about 60 operations in a 30 different classes to JMX.  Making it with `DynamicMBean` is a bit annoying.  I am looking for a fast and elegant way to do it.

I know that Spring has a nice way with annotations but i am not using spring in this project.

Comment: Anything to stop you introducing Spring into your project?

Comment: it is a long story, but i can't

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at my [SimpleJmx Java package](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) which is designed to easily publish beans via JMX using annotations.  It also has client code as well.

Quick code sample:

```
// you can also use the platform mbean server
JmxServer jmxServer = new JmxServer(8000);
jmxServer.start();
// register our lookupCache object defined below
jmxServer.register(lookupCache);
...
jmxServer.stop();
```

Here's how to define a bean.

```
@JmxResource(domainName = "j256", description = "Lookup cache")
public class LookupCache {
    @JmxAttributeField(description = "Number of hits in the cache")
    private int hitCount;
    ...

    @JmxOperation(description = "Flush the cache")
    public void flushCache() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Feedback welcome.

Comment: Feedback: move the project to github :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a set of easy operations, you could use the JMX support provided in Clojure contrib:

[Clojure Contrib](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/jmx-api.html)

Clojure compiles to Java so you would not have much problems integrating with your current project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [@MXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html) annotation, it may be what you're after, and is part of Java 6.